# How to use a clipped Raster with Raster Calculator in a script

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-processing, clip, raster-calculator

I want to make a script which will asking me a raster layer, a vector layer and a double.
The point is to clip the raster and then process to filter data, like (raster > filter)*raster.

My script without the init algorithm:

```
layer = self.parameterAsRasterLayer(parameters, self.INPUT, context)
clip = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(parameters, self.MASK, context)
filter = self.parameterAsDouble(parameters, self.FILTER,context)
cliplayer = self.parameterAsOutputLayer(parameters, self.OUTPUT_CLIP, context)
calclayer = self.parameterAsOutputLayer(parameters, self.OUTPUT_CALC, context)

        
cliplayer = processing.run("saga:cliprasterwithpolygon",
            {'INPUT':layer,
             'POLYGONS':clip,
             'OUTPUT': cliplayer}) 

processing.run("gdal:rastercalculator",
            {'INPUT_A' : cliplayer,
             'BAND_A' : 1,
             'FORMULA' : '(A >' + str(filter) + ') * A', 
             'OUTPUT' : calclayer})
```

I have an error saying the gdal:rastercalculator is invalid. But I don't know how to code it correctly, if someone could help me ! :)

---

EDIT

I find it ! I may call it back with ['OUTPUT'] as it is temporaly layers, here is my code if someone have the same problem :

```
cliplayer = processing.run("saga:cliprasterwithpolygon",
            {'INPUT':layer,
             'POLYGONS':clip,
             'OUTPUT': 'memory:' }) 

processing.run("gdal:rastercalculator",
            {'INPUT_A' : cliplayer['OUTPUT'],
             'BAND_A' : 1,
             'FORMULA' : '(A >' + str(filter) + ') * A', 
             'OUTPUT' : calclayer})
```